# How to wait for user click event in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-services

So I have two components in Angular2. When a user clicks a button in component1, I have a method that stores a data in the `sharedservice` to a variable. This variable is accessed in component2 `ngOnInit()`. However the variable in initialised to undefined in `ngOnInit()` because it doesn't wait for the click event.

All In all, how can I have angular2 component2 wait for click event in component1?

In JavaScript, we can easily do this using click event listener or have a callback function, but I don't know how to implement the same idea in angular.

Could you please share your ideas.

This is what I have so far:

**`modules.component.html`**

```js
<tr *ngFor="let module of modules" #moduleObject>
  <a class="test" (click)="module._clicked = !module._clicked"></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" [ngStyle]="{'display': module._clicked ? 'block' : 'none'}" >
    <li><a (click)="_showDialogue =! _showDialogue; _getModuleCode(module)"><img src="../../assets/img/pencil.svg" alt="" width="13px">Edit Module</a></li>

  </ul>
</tr>
```

I'll remove unecessary code from modules.component.ts as it will just blow everything in here
**`modules.component.ts`**

```js
import {SharedService} from "../shared/shared.service";
import {DepartmentsService} from "./departments.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import {Module} from "../dashboard/Module";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modules',
  templateUrl: './modules.component.html',
  providers: [DepartmentsService]
})
export class ModulesComponent implements OnInit {
  service;

  modules: Module[];

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    service : SharedService,
    private departmentsService: DepartmentsService,
    route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(p => {this.department = p['dname']; });
    this.service = service;
  }

  _getModuleCode(moduleObject) {
    this.departmentsService.moduleObject = moduleObject;
  }


  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**`departments.service.ts`**

```js
// assume necessary imports above
@Injectable()
export class DepartmentsService {
  public _facultyName     :string;
  public _departmentName  :string;
  public moduleObject:Module;
  constructor() {}
}
```

Then I call the moduleObject variable from this component:
**`edit-forms.component.html`**

```js
import {Module} from "./Module";
import {DepartmentsService} from "../components/departments.service";
//Change
@Component({
  selector: 'enable-module-form',
  templateUrl: './edit-forms.component.html',
  providers:[ModuleService]
})
export class EnableModFormComponent {
  constructor( 
    private moduleService: ModuleService, 
    private departmentService: DepartmentsService 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.departmentService.moduleObject);
  }

}
```

Comment: You would use an `Observable`. Can you post some code of your scenario so we can provide you a more realistic answer?

Comment: sure thing. Please check my latest edit above @acdcjunior

Comment: any luck? @acdcjunior

Comment: Could you please abbreivate more on how I can use observable? @acdcjunior

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work!

DepartmentService:

```
private moduleSource = new Subject<any>();
moduleValue = this.moduleSource.asObservable();

moduleValueReceived(module) {
  //emit value
  this.moduleSource.next(module)
}
```

and in your parent, when you have the value set the value in the service:

```
_getModuleCode(moduleObject) {
   this.departmentsService.moduleValueReceived(moduleObject);
}
```

and in your child constructor, subscribe to the value:

```
constructor( 
  private moduleService: ModuleService, 
  private departmentService: DepartmentsService 
) { 
     moduleService.moduleValue.subscribe(moduleObject => {
        console.log(moduleObject); // here you have your value
     })
  }
```

[**Here in the official docs**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) you have the equivalent example with further explanations than I have provided.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah thank you again. Don't know what I'll do without you. Really appreciate it. Although it did work. But for some reason, the 
`subscribe(i => i.console.log(i))` is printing the clicked element multiple times. Why is that? I just want it to return the clicked element once.

Comment: Because I have a list of buttons, and when I click the button, I get the right data, but it returns the data according to how many buttons in `ul li` I have

Comment: Well if it gets printed multiple times, that would suggest that change happens multiple times, since subscribe naturally subscribes whenever change happens :) I don't see any buttons in your code you provided? Could you elaborate a bit further? All else code seems pretty clear to me as to what's going on, but maybe show some more of the html if you indeed have some buttons there as well? So I would get a better picture on what's going on in the view :)

Comment: Ah I just realized! the reason why the data was being received is because I had the component in a `ngFor=`. It was very annoying to realise the issue. Again, really appreciate your answer!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help... :) And yeah, I think it's part of the job to have face-palm moments when you realize the error. At least I have plenty of them moments :D